# Image update on change of object variable in 2D array in Compose with Clean Architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, clean-architecture

I have a `board` variable with 2d array containing a data class `Item` and having 5 rows and columns.

Here is the structure of the `Item` object:

```
data class Item(
    val x: Int,
    val y: Int,
    var index: Int = 0,
    var isClick: Boolean = false
)
```

`ViewModel` code:

```
private val _board = mutableStateOf<Array<Array<Item>>>(arrayOf())
val board: State<Array<Array<Item>>> = _board

fun start() {
    _board.value = createBoard()// Use case that returns Array(row) { i -> Array(col) { j -> Item(i, j) } }
}
```

`Screen` code:

```
val row = 5
val col = 5
val board = remember { viewModel.board.value }

Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
    Row(Modifier.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        Column {
            for (i in 0 until row) {
                Row {
                    for (j in 0 until col) {

                        val currentItem = remember { mutableStateOf(board[i][j]) }

                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(
                                id = if (currentItem.value.isClick) {
                                    when (currentItem.value.index) {
                                        0 -> R.drawable.ic_num_0
                                        1 -> R.drawable.ic_num_1
                                        2 -> R.drawable.ic_num_3
                                        else -> R.drawable.ic_field
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    R.drawable.ic_field
                                }
                            ),
                            contentDescription = null,
                            modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                                currentItem.value = currentItem.value.copy(
                                    isClick = true
                                )
                                board[i][j].isClick = true
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when you `start()` again, the board variable is updated, but the UI doesn't recompose, the recomposition occurs in case of a configuration change, for example, a screen rotation.

The variable `currentItem`, which is a mutableStateOf-copy of the `Item` object from the `board`, is filled with these elements, and after the restart is filled with new `Item` elements with their own values, but recomposition does not occur because the created objects continue to exist, and only after the rotation and state change does the recomposition and filling with new `Item`s take place.

How can I get existing images to recomposition when changing values in `Item` objects if I can't use `Array<Array<MutableState<Item>>>` because getting the `board` data comes from the `data layer` and I can't specify the `MutableState` in the `domain layer` as it violates the **Independent of UI** Clean Architecture principle by importing the `androidx` library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `remember` here:

```
// val board = remember { viewModel.board.value }
val board = viewModel.board.value
```

board will then always be updated with the value from ViewModel.
Then use the `board` as a key to your other remember:

```
val currentItem = remember(board) { mutableStateOf(board[i][j]) }
```

This will update current item whenever board changes in the ViewModel, but it will also remember the changes you do inside of your composable (until configuration change).